# SQL Server Debezium connector is skipping the changeset

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Debezium CDC SQL Server source connector to take data from the SQL server and put it in Kafka the configurations
I tried to update the source table but the changes did not flown to kafka.
When I restarted my connector that time also it is not picked up by connector,
Getting below msg in log

> Skipping change ChangeTableResultSet {.....}as its order in the transaction 2 is smaller than or equal to the last recorded operation 00008daa:00004c30:0003(00008daa:00004c30:0002)[2] (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource)

No exception/no error.

Is there an issue with my configuration?